# Ocultar o poner en modo de lectura de campo según un valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, php7

Necesito ocultar campos o ponerlos en modo de solo lectura, dependiendo de la selección de un valor anterior ... Ejemplo:

```
Persona :
per_id,
per_dni,
per_name,
per_gender,
per_embarazo,
per_fechaparto,
per_discapacidad,
per_discapacidadetail
```

Al seleccionar el valor 1 en `per_gender` que es = *Mujer*, muestro o elimino solo la lectura de los campos `per_pregnancy` y `per_fechaparto`.

Por el contrario, si selecciono 2 en `per_gender` que es = *Masculino*, debo ocultar o leer solo los campos `per_pregnancy` y `per_fechaparto`.

Necesito hacerlo en `jquery`, `ajax` o `js`, ya que debe cambiar el estado del campo sin refrescar la página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias soluciones para esta situación todas se basan en el evento **change**, le puedes poner el evento onchange a un control y actuar cuando el valor de ese control cambia.

```
<script>
function genero()
{
    var gen = event.target;  //objeto select
    var preg = document.getElementById('per_pregnancy');
    var fec = document.getElementById('per_fechaparto');
    preg.disabled = gen.value !="F"
}
function fecha()
{
    var preg = event.target;   //objeto per_pregnancy
    var fec = document.getElementById('per_fechaparto');
    fec.disabled = !preg.checked
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form >
Género
<select id="gens"  onchange="genero()">
<option value="x" id="gen" name="gen">Género</option>
<option value="F" id="mujer" name="mujer">Femenino</option>
<option value="M" id="hombre" name="hombre">Masculinp</option>
</select>
Embarazada 
<input type="checkbox" id="per_pregnancy" name="per_pregnancy"   onchange="fecha()">
<input type="date"   id="per_fechaparto" name="per_fechaparto" disabled>
</form>
```

De entrada el campo fecha está deshabilitado hasta que el campo per_pregancy está habilitado.
La otra solución es similar pero el onchange se habilita en el formulario (form onchange="gestion()") y desde esa función se gestionan todos los cambios de manera centralizada).

Comment: Gracias Juan, me funciono a la perfeccion! nuevamente gracias por tu tiempo y conocimiento.